# Supervisord does not exit after one service crashed in a Docker container

Tags: shell-script, debian, docker, supervisord

I have the following supervisord configuration:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=NONE

[program:service1]
command=/usr/sbin/service1
user=someone
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=30

[program:service2]
command=/usr/sbin/service2
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=30
```

I'm using this configuration in a docker container. The problem is that if service1 crashes, the container continues to run as if everything is normal. How could I change this behaviour, so that the whole container exits if one service crashed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SF Q&A titled: [How to exit all supervisor processes if one exited with 0 result](https://serverfault.com/questions/760726/how-to-exit-all-supervisor-processes-if-one-exited-with-0-result) sounds like what you're looking for.

**NOTE:** This approach uses an [eventlistener](http://supervisord.org/events.html).

#### Example #1

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=NONE

[program:service1]
command=/usr/sbin/service1
user=someone
autostart=true
;autorestart=true               ; disabled
;startsecs=30                   ; disabled
process_name=service1

[program:service2]
command=/usr/sbin/service2
user=root
autostart=true
;autorestart=true               ; disabled
;startsecs=30                   ; disabled
process_name=service2

[eventlistener:service1_exit]
command=kill.py
process_name=service1
events=PROCESS_STATE_EXITED

[eventlistener:service2_exit]
command=kill.py
process_name=service2
events=PROCESS_STATE_EXITED
```

The `kill.py` script:

```
$ cat kill.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import signal

def write_stdout(s):
   sys.stdout.write(s)
   sys.stdout.flush()
def write_stderr(s):
   sys.stderr.write(s)
   sys.stderr.flush()
def main():
   while 1:
       write_stdout('READY\n')
       line = sys.stdin.readline()
       write_stdout('This line kills supervisor: ' + line);
       try:
               pidfile = open('/var/run/supervisord.pid','r')
               pid = int(pidfile.readline());
               os.kill(pid, signal.SIGQUIT)
       except Exception as e:
               write_stdout('Could not kill supervisor: ' + e.strerror + '\n')
       write_stdout('RESULT 2\nOK')
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
   import sys
main issue I forgot to point to **process_name**
```

#### Example #2

This example shows a more streamlined approach, it's still using an eventlistener but it shows how you can do the same shown above, but with just a single listener instead & shell script.

The shell script that does the killing:

```
$ cat stop-supervisor.sh
#!/bin/bash

printf "READY\n";

while read line; do
  echo "Processing Event: $line" >&2;
  kill -3 $(cat "/var/run/supervisord.pid")
done < /dev/stdin
```

The supervisord.conf:

```
$ cat supervisord.conf
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel=debug
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor

[program:service1]
command=/usr/sbin/service1
user=someone
autostart=true
;autorestart=true               ; disabled
;startsecs=30                   ; disabled
process_name=service1

[program:service2]
command=/usr/sbin/service2
user=root
autostart=true
;autorestart=true               ; disabled
;startsecs=30                   ; disabled
process_name=service2

[eventlistener:processes]
command=stop-supervisor.sh
events=PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED, PROCESS_STATE_EXITED, PROCESS_STATE_FATAL
```

#### References

- [Process Management in Docker Containers](https://blog.zhaw.ch/icclab/process-management-in-docker-containers/)
- [Killing supervisor if any of it's child processes fail](https://gist.github.com/tomazzaman/63265dfab3a9a61781993212fa1057cb)

Comment: yeah, I solved it. Each service must run in foreground. Thanks again dude!

Comment: @chevallier - sure thing, I"ll update it per your comments. I figured those wouldn't be wanted but wasn't sure if you want those `autorestart=true` and `startsecs=30`. I've left them but commented them out.

Comment: @chevallier - updated some of this, what method did you use to run the services in foreground? `redirect_stderr=true` or something else? - http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html.

Comment: I just ran each process with his corresponding "no daemon" option, e.g. `nginx -g "daemon off;"` or `php-fpm7.0 --nodaemonize`, that stopped it from crashing and I had no more errors in the supervisord logs. Also I think you must use `;` instead `#` to add comments to `supervisord.conf`.

Comment: @chevallier - OK cool. Oh yeah on the comments, I'll fix thanks.